# simple function fires when using onclick, doesn't fire when using addEventListener in JS

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener

the function doesn't work when called with addEventListener in JS, I used the same method for other function in the same project and they all work fine.

I've made it a higher order function and still doesn't fire, I wrap its expression in another function, still doesn't work.

```js
    function contenutoSkills(nomelinguaggio, item1, item2, item3) {
  document.getElementById("linguaggio").innerHTML=nomelinguaggio;
  document.getElementById("programma1").innerHTML=item1;
  document.getElementById("programma2").innerHTML=item2;
  document.getElementById("programma3").innerHTML=item3;
}
const button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => contenutoSkills('HTML', 'PG1', 'PG2', 'PG3'));
```

```html
<button id='button'>click me<button>

<p id="linguaggio"></p>
  <ul>
     <li><p id="programma1">Programma1</p></li>
     <li><p id="programma2">Programma2</p></li>
     <li><p id="programma3">Programma3</p></li>
  </ul>
```

text one and text two should appear in p when the button is clicked, but nothing happens. If I add onclick="writeText("text one", "text two") in HTML it works fine but I don't want to do things this way. thanks for answers.

Comment: It's literally just a typo, add a parentheses on the end of the code, before the last semicolon

Comment: You are missing one `)` at the end.... try `button.addEventListener('click', () => writeText("text one", "text two"));`

Comment: sorry guys for the typos, but there's none in the actual code, so I'm going to copy-paste the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `onclick` property of the button instead of addEventListener.

HTML:

```
<button id='button' onclick="contenutoSkills('html','pg1','pg2','pg3')">click me<button>

<p id="linguaggio"></p>
  <ul>
     <li><p id="programma1">Programma1</p></li>
     <li><p id="programma2">Programma2</p></li>
     <li><p id="programma3">Programma3</p></li>
  </ul
```

And within the `<script>` tag, this would the JavaScript code:

```
    function contenutoSkills(nomelinguaggio, item1, item2, item3) {
  document.getElementById("linguaggio").innerHTML=nomelinguaggio;
  document.getElementById("programma1").innerHTML=item1;
  document.getElementById("programma2").innerHTML=item2;
  document.getElementById("programma3").innerHTML=item3;
}
```

Comment: sorry, the typo was not present in the original code, I've copypasted the original code.

Comment: Instead of making an addEventListener, consider adding a `onclick` property to the button, I'm editing my answer to show the code for it

Comment: As I said onclick works fine, my question is about addEventListener not working in this particular case